# How can i set focus on a newly (automatically) rendered dom element?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, focus

I have an input field that gets replaced automatically with a textarea and same content depending on the number of characters the user has entered:

```
<textarea v-if="myString.length > 20" v-model="myString"/>
<input type="text" v-if="myString.length <= 20" v-model="myString"/>
```

The problem i have is that the focus gets lost when a user enters the 21st character. And thus the user gets irritated because when he types the 22nd character it does not appear in the textarea (no focus).
**How can i set the focus on the newly rendered textarea then?** Problem here is that it gets rendered automatically. Otherwise i could set a ref on the textarea and call focus().

Another issue is the removal of the 21st character and the switch-back from textarea to the input elment.

Comment: i tried to use autofocus (as suggested by T.J. Crowder), but unfortunately that didn't do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap the `textarea`/`input` in a component, and use its `mounted` hook to call its `focus()`, as seen in this component:

```html
<!-- AutoFocusedInput.vue -->
<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted, computed, nextTick } from 'vue'

const input = ref()

onMounted(async () => {
  await nextTick()
  input.value.focus()
})

const props = defineProps({
  modelValue: String,
  textarea: Boolean,
})

const comp = computed(() => (props.textarea ? 'textarea' : 'input'))
</script>

<template>
  <component
    :is="comp"
    ref="input"
    v-bind="$attrs"
    :value="modelValue"
    @input="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)"
  />
</template>
```

```html
<AutoFocusedInput textarea v-if="myString.length > 20" v-model="myString" />
<AutoFocusedInput v-else v-model="myString" />
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-autofocused-input?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FAutoFocusedInput.vue)

While this is technically possible, this UX is probably not ideal, and you should consider other designs that don't require focusing input like this (as indicated by @kien_coi_1997).

Answer (score 1):

(copy from my comment because this might be helpful)

Replacing an `input` element by a `textarea` is likely to create a horrible UX. Why don't you just use `textarea` from the beginning? If you want the style to change based on the input length, e.g. increase the height if there are > 20 characters, then you can use CSS to do that.

```html
<script setup>
const props = defineProps({
  modelValue: String,
})
</script>

<template>
  <textarea
    :value="modelValue"
    @input="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)"
    :rows="1"
    :style="modelValue.length > 20 ? { minHeight: '100px' } : { minHeight: '0px' }"
  />
</template>
```

```html
<AutoFocusedInput v-model="myString" />
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-autofocused-input-grmm1u?file=src/components/AutoFocusedInput.vue) (forked from @tony19)